# How to Implement django model methods

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to build a system where we run depreciation on all assets in the database. Asset models is defined as below:

```
class Asset(models.Model):  
    Asset_description=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    Tag_number=models.TextField(unique=True)
    Asset_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Monthly_Depreciation=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Current_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Asset_description
```

How can i implement the depreciation formula in the models, e.g. 
`Monthly_Depreciation=Asset_Cost/3/12` and `Current_Cost=Asset_Cost-Monthly_Depreciation`?

Comment: one note here is that attributes of classes should be using snake_case according to pep8 and it gives readability to code, You know the attribute when you see it just because it's named in a way that says so

Comment: Second note is https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as this question is very effortless and the answer is one google search away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to distinguish between calculating `Monthly_Depreciation` and `Current_Cost` values in the python code, and having them in your database.

Calculate them in the code request to add corresponding methods like:

```
class Asset(models.Model):  
    Asset_description=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    Tag_number=models.TextField(unique=True)
    Asset_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Monthly_Depreciation=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Current_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Asset_description

    def get_monthly_deprecation(self):
        return self.Asset_Cost / 3.0 / 12.0

    def get_current_cost(self):
        return self.Asset_Cost - self.Monthly_Depreciation
```

And then you should be able to call them:

```
asset: Asset = ...
monthly_deprecation = asset.get_monthly_deprecation()
current_cost = asset.get_current_cost()
```

However **that would not update the values in the database**. To update you want to explicitly change the fields of the model and save the model then. This could be wrapped into the method of the `Asset` class:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
   ...
   def update_costs(self):
       self.Monthly_Depreciation = self.get_monthly_deprecation()
       self.Current_Cost = self.get_current_cost()
       self.save()  # This method will execute the actual UPDATE SQL statement
```

After calling this `update_costs` you will get the entry in the database updated:

```
asset: Asset = ...
asset.update_costs()
# Now both the model and the database should contain
# the calculated values, so you could use them as:
asset.Monthly_Deprecation
asset.Current_Cost
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by just creating the method in the model class.

```
class Asset(models.Model):  
    Asset_description=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    Tag_number=models.TextField(unique=True)
    Asset_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Monthly_Depreciation=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Current_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Asset_description

    def get_depreceation(self):
        depreceation = # Your formula here. You can use any the model fields using self
        return depreceation
```

Model classes can have normal methods and should have methods operating on that model. You can use this by just calling the method like you normally would for any python object

```
my_asset.get_depreceation()
```

Answer (score 0):

model apart from being database instance also behaves like a standard python object so you simply define methods inside the class. In your scheme there is defined monthly depreciation as a attribute of your model but if it's dependant on other field it's better to define a simple method that returns the needed value for example:

```
class Asset(models.Model):  
    Asset_description=models.TextField(max_length=100)
    Tag_number=models.TextField(unique=True)
    Asset_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # you don't need it anymore 
    # btw if you divide somthing by 3/12 it's better to use FloatField
    # Monthly_Depreciation=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Current_Cost=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_monthly_depreciation(self):
        return self.Asset_description/3/12

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Asset_description
```

just call the method whenever you need it. And remember that convention suggests using lowercase on attributes to improve your python knowleage read the [link](https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html)